# Юнит тест на unittest в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, юнит-тесты, python-unittest

В общем, хочу влиться в автотесты, и начал с простого - калькулятора и автотеста для него, в итоге - хренасдва а не юнит-тесты.
Вот код калькулятора:

```
import math
print("Данный калькулятор создан для операций только с двумя целыми числами, а для вычисления факториала, нужно ввести любые числа")
x = int(input("Первое число: "))
y = int(input("Второе число: "))
action = input("Действие (+ - * / !): ")
class calc:
    def add(x, y):
        return x + y
    def sub(x, y):
        return x - y
    def mul(x, y):
        return x * y
    def div(x, y):
        return x / y
    def fac(z):
        return math.factorial(z)
if action == "+":
    ("Сумма =", calc.add(x, y))
elif action == "-":
    (calc.sub(x, y))
elif action == "*":
    ("Произведение =", calc.mul(x, y))
elif action == "/":
    ("Деление =", calc.div(x, y))
elif action == "!":
    z = int(input("Введите целое число: "))
    ("Факториал числа =", calc.fac(z))
else:
    ("Wenk!")
input("\n\nНажмите Enter, чтобы выйти.")
```

И вот код автотестов (неполный, там не хватает факториала)

```
import unittest
import calc
class calcTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.calc.add(4,7), 11)
    def test_subtract(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.calc.sub(10,5), 5)
    def test_multiply(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.calc.mul(3,7), 21)
    def test_divide(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.calc.div(10,2), 5)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Проблема в том, что при прогоне тестов через IDLE он ругается с сообщениями:

```
EEEE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_add (__main__.calcTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\richa\Desktop\utest_calc.py", line 5, in test_add
    self.assertEqual(self.calc.add(4,7), 11)
AttributeError: 'calcTest' object has no attribute 'calc'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_divide (__main__.calcTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\richa\Desktop\utest_calc.py", line 11, in test_divide
    self.assertEqual(self.calc.div(10,2), 5)
AttributeError: 'calcTest' object has no attribute 'calc'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_multiply (__main__.calcTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\richa\Desktop\utest_calc.py", line 9, in test_multiply
    self.assertEqual(self.calc.mul(3,7), 21)
AttributeError: 'calcTest' object has no attribute 'calc'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_subtract (__main__.calcTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\richa\Desktop\utest_calc.py", line 7, in test_subtract
    self.assertEqual(self.calc.sub(10,5), 5)
AttributeError: 'calcTest' object has no attribute 'calc'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.009s

FAILED (errors=4)
```

А если пытаюсь вывести через командную строку, то это:

```
C:\Windows\system32>python -m unittest utest_calc -v
utest_calc (unittest.loader._FailedTest) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: utest_calc (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: utest_calc
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\richa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
   module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utest_calc'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: self.assertEqual(self.calc.add(4,7), 11) - зачем здесь self перед calc?

Comment: Судя по тому примеру из которого я это брал, там так, честно, хз почему так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.calc` - это попытка обращения к полю текущего объекта (упрощенно - объекта, которому принадлежит метод, в котором происходит это обращение). По сути вы пытаетесь обратиться к полю `calc` юнит-теста. Такого поля у юнит-теста нет, отсюда ошибка.

Вам нужно убрать этот `self` перед `calc` (например, `self.assertEqual(calc.add(4,7), 11)`) и импортировать класс `calc` из модуля, где он объявлен, пример:

```
from имя_модуля import calc
```

Вместо `имя_модуля` подставьте имя файла, где находится класс `calc`, но без расширения `.py`.

Также внутри модуля с классом `calc` нужно чтобы все действия взаимодействия с пользователем не выполнялись при импорте модуля (в том числе при импорте внутри тестового модуля), для этого их нужно расположить в блоке `if __name__ == "__main__":`

```
import math

class calc:
    def add(x, y):
        return x + y
    def sub(x, y):
        return x - y
    def mul(x, y):
        return x * y
    def div(x, y):
        return x / y
    def fac(z):
        return math.factorial(z)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Данный калькулятор создан для операций только с двумя целыми числами, а для вычисления факториала, нужно ввести любые числа")
    x = int(input("Первое число: "))
    y = int(input("Второе число: "))
    action = input("Действие (+ - * / !): ")

    if action == "+":
        ("Сумма =", calc.add(x, y))
    elif action == "-":
        (calc.sub(x, y))
    elif action == "*":
        ("Произведение =", calc.mul(x, y))
    elif action == "/":
        ("Деление =", calc.div(x, y))
    elif action == "!":
        z = int(input("Введите целое число: "))
        ("Факториал числа =", calc.fac(z))
    else:
        ("Wenk!")
    input("\n\nНажмите Enter, чтобы выйти.")
```

Comment: Большое спасибо вам за ответ, да, я ошибся с self. убрав это недоразумение всё заработало, и ещё, этот код несколько неверен, т.к нет принтов, но это не страшно, а по поводу from имя_файла import имя_файла, там в обоих случаях без расширения .py, но осталась одна проблема - этот тест не воспроизводится через командную строку, выходит таже самая ошибка

Comment: @Павел должно быть не `import имя_файла`, а `from имя_файла import calc`

Comment: Не работает так

Comment: @Павел значит что-то не так делаете, у меня все работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNy3I.png